# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Контроль давления вести по манометру, установленному по месту"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая в предложении: «Контроль давления вести по манометру, установленному по месту»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая **необходима**, так как *установленному по месту* – причастный оборот. (По манометру — определяемое слово.)

Правильно:

> Контроль давления вести по манометру, установленному по месту.

(*Устанавливать по месту*, видимо, профессионализм; если нет, то стоить писать: «Установленному *на месте*».)

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая нужна:

> Обособляются распространенные определения, выраженные *причастием* или
>   прилагательным *с зависящими от него словами*, стоящие **после**
>   существительного.
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108